# Problems with Ruby encoding in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding

I wrote a simple code that reads an email from MS-Outlook, using 'win32ole', and then save its subjects to an CSV file. Everything goes well except the encoding system. When I open my CSV file the words such as "André" are printed as "Andr\x82". I want my output format to be equal to my input.

```
# encoding: 'CP850'

require 'win32ole'
require 'CSV'

Encoding.default_external = 'CP850'

ol = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
inbox = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)

email_subjecs = []

inbox.Items.each do |m|

   email_subjects << m.Subject 

end

CSV.open('MyFile.csv',"w") do |csv| 
   csv << email_subjects
end
```

O.S: Windows 7 64bit

Encoding.default_external -> CP850

Languadge -> PT

ruby -v -> 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]

It seems a simple problem related to external windows encoding and I tryied many solution posted here but I realy can't solve this.

Comment: **When I open my CSV file the words such as "André" are printed as "Andr\x82"** So what does that have to do with ruby?  Contact the manufacturer of your viewing device and ask them how to make it so that the viewing device shows 'latin small letter e with acute' instead of that hex code(you probably just have to switch a setting somewhere in your viewing device to use CP850).

Comment: To reiterate, the hex value \x82 in the encoding CP850 is  "latin small letter e with acute", so assuming you want the output file to be encoded in CP850, the correct character was written to the file.  Just because whatever viewing device you are using to look at the file doesn't understand what character \x82 is supposed to be doesn't mean your ruby script isn't working correctly.  What viewing device are you using to look at the file?  What do you get if you add the line `puts m.Subject.encoding.name`?

Comment: If I puts this line code its return "CP850".This is not an viewer device issue. Now I changed my encoding from CP850 to UTF-8 in magic comment and set Encoding.default_external = utf-8 and and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic comment only sets the encoding the current (`.rb`) file should be read as. It does not set `default_external`. Try `set RUBYOPT=-E utf-8`, open your file with `CSV.open('MyFile.csv', encoding: 'UTF-8')`, or set `Encoding.default_external` at the top of your file (discouraged).

Comment: `# encoding: utf-8`  To clarify, that comment allows you to type non-ascii characters in your *source file*, i.e. in your code.  You don't have any non-ascii characters in your code: `CSV`, `open`, `do`--they all consist of ascii characters.  And in ruby 2.1, UTF-8 is now the default for the source encoding.

Comment: Define "didn't work". Setting `Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'` did not set `Encoding.default_external` to `UTF-8`..?

Comment: It seems you're reading from Windows and writing to the file. The file operation is governed by `Encoding.default_external`, but the Windows side is AFAIK governed by `WIN32OLE.codepage`, which can be inherited from `Encoding.default_internal`. I am not on Windows, so can't tell you for sure what will work, but messing with one of those two settings might work. Also, see what encoding actual strings you read from Windows are (`m.Subject.encoding`).

Comment: @Amadan, According to the win32ole docs, in the op's code the WIN32OLE.codepage should automatically get set to Encoding.default_external--due to the fact that Encoding.default_internal is nil: *If not explicitly set this default internal encoding is nil...* (ruby Class:Encoding docs)

Comment: I changed my encoding from CP850 to UTF-8 in magic comment and set Encoding.default_external = utf-8 and and now it works. Thanks Amadan and 7stud for the Help

Comment: @LuisHenriqueCasteloBranco, Get rid of the magic comment. As explained, it does nothing in your program. And, if you are using ruby 2.0+, the default for the magic comment is UTF-8 anyway.

Comment: @LuisHenriqueCasteloBranco, \x82 is not a valid character in the UTF-8 encoding, so I fail to understand how your new code somehow converts that to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your file name is missing a closing quote.

2) The default open mode for CSV.open() is 'rb', so you can't possibly write to a file with the code you posted.

3) You didn't post the encoding of the text you are trying to write to the file.

4) You didn't post the encoding that you want the the data to be written in.

5)

> When I open my CSV file the words such as "é" are printed as "\x82"

Tell your viewing device not to do that.